# Adding fullcalendar events with datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, datetimepicker

Is there a way to add event to fullcalendar with datetimepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)?
I need a button that will show datetimepicker onclick and then user can select date and time and insert it into database connected with fullcalendar.

This is my fullcalendar code (part of it):

```
events: {
    url: 'events.php',
    cache: true,
    type: 'POST',
    data:{userid:uid}
},

eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if(event.status == 'open') {
        element.css('background-color', 'green');
    }
},
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var status = 'open';
    var userid= <?php echo "$userid"; ?>;
    if (status) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'events_add.php',
            data: 'status='+ status+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&userid='+ userid,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                alert('Added Successfully');
            }
        });
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
            title: title,
            status: status,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
        },
        true);
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

and datetimepicker call:

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below, For getting event date, use equivalent method from your datetimepicker plugin insted of 'onSelect:';

```
    var event = {eventName:'aaaa', title:'bbbb'}; // sample event stored 
onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {
    addEvent(event, $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
}

function(event, date){
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, event);
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

}
```